# how to maintain a radix tree in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use a in memory radix tree for prefix based search. Is it possible to maintain radix tree in neo4j? Does neo4j support radix tree?
please share any code snippet if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [RadixTree implementation](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graph-collections/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/collections/radixtree/RadixTreeImpl.java) in Neo4j back in 2014, but the project is likely out of date. Unsure if that will work for you, but it may be a good place to start if you're planning on implementing one yourself.

If you just need support for property prefix searches, Neo4j is using Lucene under the hood, and schema indexes support [STARTS WITH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GZ8S.jpg) searches of indexed properties.

So you could either index lookup properties on the nodes you want directly, or you could create :Entry reference nodes with indexed `name` properties, and use STARTS WITH lookups to find the :Entry, then traverse a relationship to whatever node that :Entry should reference.

Comment: I'll try to explain the required behavior through an example -
the length of the keys is constant. let's say the tree has following two keys 496123757160001 and 496123757160009. we need to find all the nodes below 49612375716000. So with above two nodes we should get two nodes representing the last digit 1 and 9. with this the next available node would be 2 and this way we'll insert 496123757160002 in the tree. if all the leaf nodes at last last digit (1 through 9) are occupied we go one level up and search with sub key 4961237571600, and so on.

Comment: You won't be able to use looping in Cypher, so that kind of logic (retry with with the sub key if no results found) will either have to be in a custom procedure, or handled outside the db call server-side.